# Get all values from multiple dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am new to .NET, and I am trying to get both values from the first and second dropdown. Say, both dropdowns don't have IDs, and I don't have control over how many they are going to be.

I have the following aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            lblResult.InnerHtml = "asd";
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:dropdownlist runat="server">
                <asp:listitem value="A">A</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem value="B">B</asp:listitem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>

            <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" multiple>
                <asp:listitem value="C">C</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem value="D">D</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem value="E">E</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem value="F">E</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem value="G">E</asp:listitem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>

            <asp:button id="btnClick" runat="server" onclick="btnClick_Click" text="Click"></asp:button>

            <span id="lblResult" runat="server"></span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Say, on the first dropdown **A** is selected, and on the second dropdown **C** and **F** are selected.

Expecting the following output:

```
Combined Values: A,C,F
Separated Values in JSON Format: {"dropdown1":"A","dropdown2":["C","F"]}
```

Edit 1: See complete codes above.

Edit 2: Looking for two outputs without AJAX

Edit 3: Re-phrase "dropdowns are dynamically appended" to "I don't have control over how many dropdowns are going to be." to avoid confusion.

Edit 4: This is almost the same question as: [Get selected option for all DropDown-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328245/get-selected-option-for-all-dropdown-lists) ...however the accepted answer only select the last selected value from the multiple`<select>`element.

Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid your question is too broad because there are many ways to do this: AJAX, regular postback, with a model, without a model etc...You need to show us your code behind code so we can see what you are doing and how. Plus it will show that you have put some effort into doing it yourself.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I'm trying to achieve this without js. It's just a one page program. I just want to know how to iterate the values selected within the select elements.

Comment: all you need to do is give your dropdowns IDs.  Maybe I misunderstood but  "Both dropdowns don't have IDs, as they are going to be dynamically appended." is contradictory to how asp.net is supposed to work.

Comment: +1 to DaniDev's answer. If you give them IDs then you will be able to access the selected values server side. What do you mean by dynamically appended?

Comment: @Miko Your page shouldn't compile, you need id's to run a control as denoted by DaniDev.

Comment: This is just a test program, as I can't remember the exact real codes. The real one has its <select> element generated by angular, thus I said, the dropdowns won't have their IDs nor I have control over their numbers. So I'm looking for a way on how to iterate the values selected in all <select> elements in the page. Saw an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328245/get-selected-option-for-all-dropdown-lists but was not properly explained. In addition, I was looking for the combination of multiple/non-multiple <select>s if possible. I'm not sure if I'm making any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic, as the server will pre-render your controls before the page becomes visible by the browser.  Since you don't want Ajax, you're forced into the spaghetti known as the page load event.  Basically, you're attempting to create, validate, store, and output.  That horrendous approach would be:

```
var output = String.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownA.SelectedValue))
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownB.SelectedValue))
          output = $"{dropdownA.SelectedValue} {dropdownB.SelectedValue}";
```

That would be in the page load, so every time you do a post-back the check would occur.  Also, the change in values should be within your `HttpContext`.  You'll also want to make sure you tell the control to reload, so the control executes a server event every time a change occurs.  Obviously, you will have a lot of screen flickering.